# Three.js - toggle between OrbitControls and FirstPersonControls

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I am trying to toggle back and forth between three.js OrbitControls and FirstPersonControls. [Per Mr. Doob's comment on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304998/switch-threejs-controls-from-trackball-to-flycontrols-and-vice-versa) and [DVPassos's example](http://webgl.zelda.com.br/index2.html?m=Ghirahim), I have tried to make my own button that switches between the two controls.

My html has:

```
<button id="controla" type="button" class="btn btn-default">1st</button>
<button id="controlb" type="button" class="btn btn-default">3rd</button>
<script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="js/FirstPersonControls.js"></script>
```

My three.js javascript has:

```
$( 'button#controlb' ).addClass( 'active' );

$( 'button#controla' ).click( function() {
    if( !$( 'button#controla' ).hasClass( 'active' ) ){
        $( 'button#controla' ).addClass( 'active' );
        $( 'button#controlb' ).removeClass( 'active' );

        var prevCamera = camera;

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR );
        camera.position.set( 2000, 1500, 2000 );
        camera.lookAt( myTarget.position );
        camera.position.copy( prevCamera.position );
        camera.rotation.copy( prevCamera.rotation );

        controls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls(camera);
    }
});

$( 'button#controlb' ).click( function() {
    if( !$( 'button#controlb' ).hasClass( 'active' ) ){
        $( 'button#controla' ).removeClass( 'active' );
        $( 'button#controlb' ).addClass( 'active' );

        var prevCamera = camera;

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR );
        camera.position.set( 2000, 1500, 2000 );
        camera.lookAt( myTarget.position );
        camera.position.copy( prevCamera.position );
        camera.rotation.copy( prevCamera.rotation );

        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
    }
});
```

When I toggle it to First Person, the model disappears. Also, in IE console when I type `camera.position` after hitting the button, I get `[object Object] {x: NaN, y: NaN, z: NaN}`.

What am I missing here? Do I need to specify more controls?

Comment: I helped someone with pretty much the exact same thing a couple of days ago. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30206243/how-to-switch-three-js-camera-controls-from-first-person-to-orbit-and-back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30206243/how-to-switch-three-js-camera-controls-from-first-person-to-orbit-and-back)

Comment: The issue what that FirstPersonControls requires the clock to be passed to the controls update in the `animate();` function. `controls.update( clock.getDelta() );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not working because FirstPersonControls require a clock to function. I did not pass the `controls.update();` function the clock as shown below.

```
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  controls.update( clock.getDelta() );
  update();
  render();
  stats.update();
}
```