# First Person Controls breaks scene in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have created a simple scene in three. Basically just some flashing 3d text. I wanted to implement the [first person controls](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/FirstPersonControls) rather than orbit controls yet when I do the whole scene breaks.

Here is my working code:

```
import './style.css'
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
import { TTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/TTFLoader';
import { FontLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/FontLoader';
import { TextGeometry } from 'three/examples/jsm/geometries/TextGeometry';
import { Reflector } from 'three/examples/jsm/objects/Reflector.js';
import { FirstPersonControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/FirstPersonControls.js';

let glow = 0.5;

/* CREATE CAMERA */

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 100, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 1000);
camera.position.set( -30, 50, 100 );
camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );

/* END CAMERA */


/* CREATE SCENE & FOG */

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
var setcolor = 0x707070;

//scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(setcolor, 1, 100);
//scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(setcolor, 0.05);

/* END SCENE & FOG */



/* CREATE RENDERER */

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true, alpha: true } );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.setAnimationLoop( animation );
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

/* END RENDERER */


/* CREATE ORBIT CONTROLS */

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

/* END ORBIT CONTROLS */


/* CREATE LIGHTS */

const rectLight = new THREE.RectAreaLight( 0xf9d71c, glow, 150, 30 );
scene.add( rectLight );
rectLight.position.set( 5, 23, 5 );
rectLight.lookAt( 0, 0, 120 );

const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.3, 100 );
pointLight.position.set( 0, 50, -50 );
scene.add( pointLight );
pointLight.castShadow = true;

/* END LIGHTS */


/* CREATE TEXT */


  /* CREATE 3D FONT */
  let text = "TEST";
  let textMesh;

  const loader = new FontLoader();
  loader.load('node_modules/three/examples/fonts/droid/droid_serif_regular.typeface.json', function (font) {
    const textGeometry = new TextGeometry(text, {
      font: font,
      size: 40,
      height: 5,
      curveSegments: 12,
      bevelEnabled: true,
      bevelThickness: 5,
      bevelSize: 2,
      bevelOffset: 2,
      bevelSegments: 15
    });

    textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, [
      new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ emissive: 0xf9d71c, emissiveIntensity: glow }),
      new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffffff })
    ]);

    scene.add( textMesh );

    textMesh.position.set( -75, 3, 0 )

    textMesh.castShadow = true;
    textMesh.receiveShadow = true;

  })


/* END TEXT */


animation();



//Animation
function animation() {

  requestAnimationFrame( animation );
  glow = Math.random() - 0.1;
  textMesh.material[0].emissiveIntensity = glow;
  rectLight.intensity = glow;



  controls.update();
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

If I replace the orbit controls line `const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);` with the following first person controls line(s)

```
controls = new FirstPersonControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.movementSpeed = 150;
controls.lookSpeed = 0.1;
```

then the whole scene breaks. What I mean by "breaks" is that any mesh I have in the scene, in this case the 3D text, randomly vanishes. Why does it do that and how can I implement the first person controls?

**EDIT**

I added clock to the controls with

```
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
//Animation
function animation() {

  requestAnimationFrame( animation );
  glow = Math.random() - 0.01;
  textMesh.material[0].emissiveIntensity = glow;
  rectLight.intensity = glow;

  controls.update( clock.getDelta() );   //updated line
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

and everything is still hidden.

**EDIT #2**

I moved `var clock = new THREE.Clock();` inside the `animation()` function and all the objects are now visible yet another problem has occurred.
I can see the objects but the camera is not moving when I use WASD or the arrow keys.

** FINAL EDIT **

Sorry for all the edits. I moved `var clock = new THREE.Clock();` out of the `animation()` function and declared it as global, and everything works as expected.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263264/three-js-toggle-between-orbitcontrols-and-firstpersoncontrols

Comment: We’re gonna need more details. Are you importing the FirstPersonControls? Are you re-assigning a value to a `const`? Are you calling `update()` without a delta value as an argument?

Comment: @James I added the clock to controls.update() inside the animation function and everything is still hidden.

Comment: @Marquizzo Yes, I imported FirstPersonControls with ```import { FirstPersonControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/FirstPersonControls.js';```. I just added a delta value in the ```update()``` call in the animation function and still no luck.